# Nodemailer is changing custom header keys

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

Short description:

What I have:

```
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    SES: ses
});    

const mailOptions = {
    from: `"${message.fromName}" <${addresses.from}>`,
    subject: message.subject,
    html: html,
    ...        
    textEncoding: "quoted-printable",
    encoding: "utf-8", 
    headers: {
        'X-MailType': message.name,
        'X-Mail-RequestUuid': message.requestUuid            
    }
}

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
```

When the email arrives to the inbox:

```
X-Mailtype: Test
X-Mail-Requestuuid: xxxxxxx-x-x-xx-x-x-x--x-x-x
```

Expected:

```
X-MailType: Test
X-Mail-RequestUuid: xxxxxxx-x-x-xx-x-x-x--x-x-x
```

It is changing the case of the headers keys.

**UPDATE:**

I have found this param in createTransport:

```
    // use a normalizer method for header keys
    normalizeHeaderKey: key => key.toUpperCase()
```

> normalizeHeaderKey(key) – a method that is applied to every header key
> before inserting to generated rfc822 message.

I added to my code:

```
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    SES: ses,
    normalizeHeaderKey: key => key
});
```

Trying to override some default behavior but got the same result in case mismatch:
What I have set configure: X-MailType
What I get in mail: X-Mailtype

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

This is the only and less cool solution I found:

```
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    SES: ses,
    normalizeHeaderKey: (key) => {
        if(key === 'X-Mailtype'){
            return 'X-MailType';
        }else if(key === 'X-Mail-Requestuuid'){
            return 'X-Mail-RequestUuid';
        }else{
            return key;
        }
    }
});
```

:/